# Bold text - gvim

Tags: vim, config

How to establish a font **Monaco** of size **10** on gvim?

```
: set guifont = Courier \ 14.
```

How to make this font is bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On gVim (not terminal Vim) you can do `:set guifont=*`.

It brings a font selection dialog where you can choose desired font family, style and size. After that `:set guifont?` gives you a string which you can use in any vimscript file like `.gvimrc` (escape spaces with backslash `\`).

On my Ubuntu box if I choose Monaco Bold `:set guifont?` outputs `guifont=Monaco Bold` so entering `:set guifont=Monaco\ Bold` give me the bold font.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [VimWikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_the_font_in_the_GUI), you can pass parameters to set the weight. In this case the weight would be 50, which is default.

```
set guifont=Courier\ New/11/-1/5/50/0/0/0/1/0
```

The parameters are in the following order:

```
font family (in this example, "Courier New")
point size (default = 10)
pixel size (-1 = default)
style hint (what to do if requested family can't be found; 5 = AnyStyle = default)
weight (50 = normal, 25 = light, 63 = semibold, 75 = bold, 87 = black)
italic (0 = no)
underline (0 = no)
strikeout (0 = no)
fixedPitch (1 = yes)
raw (0 = no)
```